# Possible to hide sidebar in Genymotion device?

Tags: android, genymotion

Is it possible to hide the sidebar (volume up / down, etc) in a Genymotion device? If its not in the free plan, is it in included in the paid plan?

Comment: whats ur use case?

Comment: for a showcase on an exhibition

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is possible.

Mac OS X: Cmd + T
Windows / Linux: Ctrl + T

There is a list of all shortcuts:
https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/03_Virtual_Devices/Virtual_device_shortcuts.htm

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to hide the side bar today.

But Genymotion devices support full screen. This will put on the side bar on the extreme right of the screen that could fit the use case.

If you remain on personal use however, you will have the "Personal Use" overlay at the bottom of the screen that could be disturbing.

Comment: I think this would be a useful feature to create gif from genymotion so that it doesn't show the sidebar on the gif.

Comment: @Simon you already have a screencast feature on Genymotion that records videos of the device screen (without the side bar). You can then easy convert them to GIF using ffmpeg or online services.